# Nim equivalent of Python's list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nim-lang

Since Nim shares a lot of features with Python, i would not be surprised if it implements [Python's list comprehension](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html#list-comprehensions) too:

```
string = "Hello 12345 World"
numbers = [x for x in string if x.isdigit()]
# ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Is this actually possible in Nim? If not, could be implemented with templates/macros ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE**: List comprehension has been deprecated since version 0.19.9 ([Source](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/tree/master/lib/pure/sugar.nim#L130)). A good alternative is to use [the new sugar.collect macro](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sugar.html#collect.m%2Cuntyped%2Cuntyped).

Another update: As of 2023, list comprehension has been removed.

---

**Outdated original answer**

List comprehension is implemented in Nim in the [`sugar` package](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sugar.html) (i.e., you have to `import sugar`). It is implemented as a macro called `lc` and allows to write list comprehensions like this:

```
lc[x | (x <- 1..10, x mod 2 == 0), int]

lc[(x,y,z) | (x <- 1..n, y <- x..n, z <- y..n, x*x + y*y == z*z), tuple[a,b,c: int]]
```

Note that the macro requires to specify the type of the elements.

Comment: @Downvoter: Surprised to get downvotes here. Is it just because the other answer has been updated or is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Your answer is right, and since you were the first that commented on future module, i'll mark yours  as the correct.

Comment: List comprehensions are deprecated since version 0.19.9.

Comment: For a library-based solution check out https://github.com/alehander42/comprehension

Comment: the prefered way of doing this is with the collect macro in sugar https://nim-lang.org/docs/sugar.html#collect.m%2Cuntyped%2Cuntyped

Comment: @daten-kieker That information that the answer is outdated is written in the first paragraph of the answer. I'll try to make it even more obvious...

Comment: @bluenote10 - sorry, my bad. Too focused on the code snippet, I guess. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 9):

<s>According to [rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code), [Nim has no list comprehensions, but they can be created through metaprogramming](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/List_comprehensions#Nim).</s>

**[EDIT]**

As pointed out by bluenote10, list comprehensions are now part of the [future module](http://nim-lang.org/docs/future.html):

```
import future
var str = "Hello 12345 World"
echo lc[x | (x <- str, ord(x) - ord('0') in 0..9),  char]
```

The above snippet yields `@[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what is now part of the `future` module.

Comment: As of 2023-06-17 this answer doesn't work anymore. The new way is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396753/5389964) by @dotfelixb)

Answer (score 7):

Original

```
import sugar

let items = collect(newSeq):
  for x in @[1, 2, 3]: x * 2

echo items
```

outputs `@[2, 4, 6]`

Updated to answer question

```
import sugar
import sequtils
import strutils

let numbers = collect: # collect from suger
  for x in "Hello 12345 World".toSeq: # toSeq from sequtils
    if x.isDigit: # isDigit from strutils
      x

echo numbers
```

outputs `@['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']`

Answer (score 2):

Nim translation of your code:

```
import sugar, strutils
var str = "Hello 12345 World"
echo collect(for s in str:
  if s.isDigit(): s)
```